# Why does the escape key have a delay in Python curses?

Tags: python, keyboard, python-curses

In the Python `curses` module, I have observed that there is a roughly 1-second delay between pressing the <kbd>esc</kbd> key and `getch()` returning.  This delay does not seem to occur for other keys.  Why does this happen and what can I do about it?

Test case:

```
import curses
import time

def get_delay(window, key):
    while True:
        start = time.time()
        ch = window.getch()
        end = time.time()
        if ch == key:
            return end-start

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.nodelay(1)

    stdscr.addstr("Press ESC")
    esc_delay = get_delay(stdscr, 27)

    stdscr.addstr("\nPress SPACE")
    space_delay = get_delay(stdscr, ord(' '))

    return esc_delay, space_delay

if __name__ == '__main__':
    esc_delay, space_delay = curses.wrapper(main)
    print("Escape delay: {} ms".format(esc_delay*1000))
    print("Space delay: {} ms".format(space_delay*1000))
```

Results:

```
Escape delay: 1001.09195709 ms
Space delay: 0.00596046447754 ms
```

Comment: The delay is to wait for following characters that may make a valid escape sequence

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In order to customize the Esc delay you can set the environment variable ESCDELAY which curses uses to determine the time in milliseconds it waits before it delivers the Escape Key.

In order to define this variable in Python you could for example call the following function prior to your call to `curses.wrapper(main)`:

```
def set_shorter_esc_delay_in_os():
    os.environ.setdefault('ESCDELAY', '25')
```

which will set the environment variable to 25ms if it has not been set before.

See also the [man page of ncurses](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses) (search for ESCDELAY).

Comment: Mmh ok, don't have OS X, but according this [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/ncurses.3x.html), ncurses should be aware of the ESCDELAY environment variable..

Comment: This works but it has to be called before initializing curses.

Comment: In C, there are two functions named `set_escdelay` and `get_escdelay`. When using these functions, the delay is measured in milliseconds.

Comment: @ManuelAtWork They also added these functions into python in python 3.9. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Curses deals with "escape sequence"s from your terminal to represent commands to the software These sequences normally begin with an escape character. Consequently, when you hit ESC the curses code doesn't emit anything immediately in case this represents the start of an escape sequence.

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: I don't know, but I rather doubt it - it's driven by the capabiities of the terminal on which curses runs

Answer (score 2):

To anyone still looking, Python 3.9 added `curses.get_escdelay()` and `curses.set_escdelay(ms)` for controlling the delay after `ESC` is pressed. Units are milliseconds. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.get_escdelay).

For example, calling

```py
curses.set_escdelay(25)
```

will set the delay to 25 milliseconds.

Now that this is available, I think it is cleaner than the accepted method:

```py
os.environ.setdefault('ESCDELAY', '25')
```

Answer (score -2):

ESCDELAY=25 ...put this in global.

Comment: What does this parameter control?  What are the units?  How do I set it?